# R Help: Make sure code is calculating sum of participants in active programs over time

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm working on a research project and repurposed some code to complete a task (which appears to have worked) but wanted help breaking down exactly what it is doing.

Essentially, I have a data frame of science programs with:

- master_data$Enrollment - a number of students
- master_data$Start - a start date
- master_data$Completion - an end date

For each date, I want to sum the participants of active programs only, where a program is active if the date considered falls between the start and completion date of the respective program.

Here's what I have:

```
indx <- lapply(unique(master_data[["Completion"]]), '%within%', interval(master_data[["Start"]], master_data[["Completion"]]))

ppl_over_time <- cbind.data.frame(DAY=unique(master_data$Completion),
                 students=unlist(lapply(indx, function(x) sum(master_data$Enrollment[x]))))
```

Here's a subset of my data:

```
structure(list(Enrollment = c(6L, 52L, 45L, 33L, 21L, 2L, 22L, 
40L, 81L, 12L), Completion = structure(c(19297, 19523, 
18809, 18597, 20543, 16832, 18901, 18932, 19388, 18158), class = "Date"), 
    Start = structure(c(18241, 16296, 17766, 12753, 18535, 
    16252, 17849, 17918, 13070, 13405), class = "Date")), row.names = c(6L, 
10L, 13L, 14L, 25L, 31L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you share a subset of your data?    If you type dput(yourdfname[1:10,c("yourvar1","yourvar2","yourvar3")])  and then paste the output into your original message we can help more. Of course, you will need to change the name of the dataframe and variables specific to your question.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Hopefully this will help more!

Comment: I'm a little confused; don't we need to know a student's date of activity, so we can test whether it falls in the ranges you provided? If that's the case, I'd also expect one record per student, permitting a test of each student. Next, we could sum students who meet the date range criteria.

Comment: Not quite. The data points are programs, each with a start date, end date, and number of participants. For each date in the entire interval of possible start and end dates (for example January 3, 2019), I would like to sum the number of participants for programs that are "active" on January 3. Hopefully that's more clear?